# Pass parameter to Fragment with Navigation

Tags: java, android, navigation

Is it possible to pass parameter to Fragment using Navigation?

Fragment:

```
class ExampleFragment(val nExampleFragmentParameter: ExampleFragmentEnum):
```

where ExampleFragmentEnum has "HOME, TOP_NEWS, VIDEO_NEWS"

I want to use the Navigation component as   *Navigation.findNavController(mNavHostFragment).navigate(R.id.exampleFragment, args);*
also passing the **ExampleFragmentEnum.TOP_NEWS** as parameter

also the navigation xml contains

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/exampleFragment"
    android:name="package.ExampleFragment"
    android:label="example_fragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_example">
    <argument
        android:name="exampleFragmentEnum"
        app:argType="package.ExampleFragmentEnum"
        android:defaultValue="HOME" />
</fragment>
```

Ps. I know you can pass data with args but I wonder if it's a way with the parameter

Comment: You should look at https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate

Comment: why not use safeArgs? https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args, Fragment creation is managed by Android so it wouldn't be a good practice to make a fragment constructor and pass arguments (I don't know if it's possible). Thats why safeArgs were created.

Comment: I think I'm gonna use safeArgs after all, was curious if it's possible to call the fragment with params :D